# nsight debugging with OpenGL interop

Tags: c++, debugging, opengl, cuda, nsight

Usually I program on Linux, now I'v setup a Windows environment just to debug with the nsight version of Visual Studio.

But when I try to start the debugger (either Graphics or CUDA Debugging), it doesn't work. The CUDA debugger just disconnects and the Graphics debugger disconnects with

```
FrameDebugger: Unsupported operation encountered; saving compatibility log to 'C:\Users\##\Documents\NVIDIA Nsight\nvcompatlog.txt'
```

The file then says

```
cuGraphicsGLRegisterImage (Registering GL textures for CUDA-Interop is unsupported)
```

Does it mean there is no way to debug CUDA, when there is interop present? It's hard to believe and so I want to make sure the problem is not on my computer only.

Comment: As it looks from your error log you can't debug CUDA-OPENGL interop.

Comment: the error log is written only in the graphics debugger. Additionally i think that a lot of cuda apps are using opengl for output, so it would be a big drawback. that's why i find it hard to believe..

Comment: I have a very similar issue. It seems like cuda-gdb on linux is actually more capable? https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/841735/cuda-programming-and-performance/should-the-nsight-cuda-debugger-work-with-opengl-interop-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cuGraphicsGLRegisterImage is not supported in Graphics Debugger as the nvcomlog.txt said.
The Cuda Debugger should work. Please contact devtools-support@nvidia.com, you may be asked for the code.